# Showing that $\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{dz}{z^4+1} = \pi $?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification

In the text, "Complex Analysis 2nd Edition"  by Eberhard Freitag and Rolf Busam I'm having difficulties verifying my proof of $\text{Proposition (1.0) - (1.3)}$. Is the following proof correct?

$\text{Proposition (1.0)}$

Let $\gamma_{R}^{1},\gamma_{R}^{2}$ be the curve sketched in the figure with $R>1$ ,and $f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^{2}}$ . One must show that

$(1.1)$

$$\oint_{\gamma}f(z)dz = \oint_{\gamma_{R}^{1}}f(z)dz + \oint_{\gamma_{R}^{2}}f(z)dz = \pi$$

$(1.2)$

$$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \bigg | \oint_{\gamma_{R}^{2}} f(z) dz \bigg | = 0. $$

$(1.3)$

$$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}dx = \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}dx = \pi $$

One can pick a Semicircular Contour $\gamma_{R}$ assuming that $R > 1$. Indeed we have

$$\gamma_{R}^{1}(t) =  t + i0 \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,  \, \, \, \text{if} \, \,  -R \leq t \leq R$$

$$\gamma_{R}^{2}(t) =  Re^{it} \, \, \text{if} \, \, \, \, 0\leq t \leq \pi$$

$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,   \, \, \, \, \, \,\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, ,\, \, \, $ [image]

$\text{Remark}$

We call these two curves, take together, $\gamma$  or $\gamma_{R}$

To prove $(1.2)$ it's trivial to notation that

$$\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{1+z^{2}}dz = \oint_{\gamma_{R}^{1}}\frac{1}{1+z^{2}}dz + \oint_{\gamma_{R}^{2}}\frac{1}{1+z^{2}}dz.$$

Finally we evaluate the integral using the Cauchy Integral Formula

$(**)$

$$\oint_{\gamma_{R}^{1} + \gamma_{R}^{2}} \frac{1}{1+z^{2}}dz = \oint_{\gamma_{R}^{1} + \gamma_{R}^{2}} \frac{f(z)}{(z+1)^{}}dz = (2 \pi i) \cdot f(z) = \pi.$$

To provide a proof for $(1.2)$, one needs to craft the upper bound for $\gamma_{R}^{2}(t)$ hence we will need the Estimation Lemma.

Using the Estimation Lemma one has the following bound,

$(***)$

$$\bigg |\oint_{\gamma_{R}^{2}} \frac{1}{1+z^{2}} dz  \bigg | \leq \big\{\text{length}(\gamma_{R}^{2}) \big\} \cdot \sup_{\gamma_{R}^{2}}|\frac{1}{1+z^{2}}|\leq \pi R \cdot \frac{1}{R^{2} - 1}.$$

It's trivial to see that,

$$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}\bigg | \oint_{\gamma_{R}^{2}}\frac{1}{1+z^{2}} dz \bigg| \rightarrow 0.$$

Finally combining  $(**)$, $(***)$ we get the following

$$\pi = \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \oint_{\gamma_{R}} \frac{1}{1+z^{2}}dz = \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \oint_{\gamma_{R}^{1}}\frac{1}{1+z^{2}}dz + \lim_{R \rightarrow  \infty }\oint_{\gamma_{R}^{2}}\frac{1}{1+z^{4}}dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + t^{4}}dt + 0.$$

Comment: there are many typos/mistakes that make your text hard to follow, please clean it up for a proper review. just to name a few: eq (1.3) has no content; there is lemma (0.0).

Comment: Yeah sure i'll retex it up

Comment: all of your work you are analyzing $\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{1+z^2}\ dz$  But the title says  $\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{1+z^4}\ dz$ and the last line $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+t^4}\ dt$  So, which is it?

Comment: @DougM Judging by how it's only the title and a tiny portion of the final line that says $1/(1+z^4)$, I'd say the intended problem uses$$f(z)=\frac 1{1+z^2}$$as the function under consideration.

Comment: Aside from the little typo with the equations, I'd say your work looks alright.